# Exception org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [] threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

While moving from Java 8 to Java 11 I am getting the following exception

```
   Exception org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [health-    servlet] threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error i upgraded the version in pom

```
 -        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
 +        <jersey.version>2.30.1</jersey.version>
```

I had this in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>health-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xyz.platform.registry.service.ServiceRegistryApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```